# Room privilege Relation with query

Tags: android, android-room

I have two tables.

Table Decks:

```
Decks:
-id
-name
```

Table Cards:

```
Cards:
-id
-name
-deckId
```

I created a data class for this query:

```
data class DeckWithDueDatedCards(

        @Embedded
        var deckEntity: DeckEntity,

        var list: List<CardEntity>

)
```

I removed the `@Relation` top of list, because it's queried all cards.
I want to add a condition. So I don't need all card, from the deck.
Let see:

I created the next Query:

```
@Query("SELECT *, (SELECT  * FROM cards WHERE deckId = D.id AND dueDate < date('now')) as list  FROM decks D WHERE D.id = :deckId")
fun getDeckWithDueDatedCards(deckId: Long): Flowable<DeckWithDueDatedCards>
```

But I got an error, because the inner select is bad. It can't inflate the list.

```
There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (sub-select returns 8 columns - expected 1)
public abstract io.reactivex.Flowable<....database.entity.DeckWithDueDatedCards> getDeckWithDueDatedCards(long deckId);
```

I see the issue is the Inner select have 8 item, but it's except only 1. But I have a list there. How to inflate it?

Anyone have idea how to fix this issue? It's possible with query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room Dao's allow non abstract method.

If you want to getDeckWithDueDatedCards you can write a method that gonna load all `CardEntity` first, and then load linked `DeckEntity` to build your `DeckWithDueDatedCards`

Java code :

```
@Query("SELECT *  FROM decks WHERE id = :deckId")
public abstract DeckEntity loadDeck(int deckId);

@Query("SELECT  * FROM cards WHERE deckId = D.id AND dueDate < :date")
public abstract Flowable<List<CardEntity>> loadCardEntity(String date);

@Transaction
public Flowable<DeckWithDueDatedCards> getDeckWithDueDatedCards(int deckId, String date) {
    return loadCardEntity(date)
            .map(cardEntityList -> {
                List<DeckWithDueDatedCards> res = new ArrayList<>();
                for(CardEntity cardEntity : cardEntityList) {
                    res.add(new DeckWithDueDatedCards(cardEntity, loadDeck(deckId)));
                }
                return res;
            });
}
```

note: be aware that modification on `CardEntity` gonna trigger `onNext` on your `subscriber`, but modifications on `DeckEntity` won't ...

edit: if you need to be notify on `DeckEntity` changes update `loadCardEntity` query

```
@Query("SELECT  cards.* FROM cards INNER JOIN decks ON cards.deckId = decks.id WHERE deckId = D.id AND dueDate < :date")
public abstract Flowable<List<CardEntity>> loadCardEntity(String date);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll separate my Dao functions. 1 for flowable, 1 for List. It can save me sometime about Rx.

Comment: If Deck is changing, than it's isn't emitting. Do you have idea how to fix it?

Comment: You have to join DeckEntity in your loadCardEntity query.

Comment: Thank you. It's looks like a little hack, I think.

Comment: Is it able to do with RxJava?

Comment: I don't think it's a hacky way to do it.
Room need to know what data you want to watch, that's why you need to join with decks table